# Seams in beadboard ceiling

Tags: repair, plywood

[image]

My porch was just built today.  They stained it, but don't like the seams.  Can I caulk with regular wood filler, or silicone, since it is outside?  I guess I will paint over the stain.

Comment: Is this 4x8 ft sheets? If so, maybe additional nails at the seams ould close them.

Comment: The picture is fuzzy is that a T1-11 siding they used? The only way to hide that seam would be to use a trim Baton or a pice of trim to cover the joint, calking may actually make it look worse.